# Visual Studio Code: Is there a distribution available for Intel debian ? The one available for debian is for amd64

Tags: visual-studio-code

https://code.visualstudio.com/

It lists deb and rpm but the deb is for amd64

Comment: AMD64 just means 64-bit x86. It runs fine on Intel processors that support 64-bit extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's called `amd64` is simply that AMD beat Intel to market with the first 64-bit x86-compatible CPU, and therefore their version (which actually just extended the old `x86` instruction set with new 64-bit variants) became the standard. You can most certainly use that version no matter what vendor your CPU is from as long as it supports x86 with 64-bit extensions.

Intel also tried with their own new architecture called Itanium (IA64), but that never really got enough traction (I don't think they ever made more than one generation of those chips?).

**EDIT** I see you're running 32-bit Linux, so you should get the [32-bit .deb version](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/?dv=linux32_deb)

Comment: There were like 4 or 5 generations of Itanium. It was moderately successful in the enterprise world, but it never caught on among consumers because it was too radical a change.

Comment: @CodyGray interesting to know! I didn't realise that it lived that long, but if course - you still see some Linux distributions support it. :)

Comment: Thanks ! That is really informative. The CPU that I have is (http://ark.intel.com/products/53480/Intel-Pentium-Processor-G620-3M-Cache-2_60-GHz) which says it is 64 bit but apt-get errors out saying its wrong architecture. Tried using the executable in the zip version but same result.

Comment: @SudhirK what is the output from `uname -a`? (just run it in a terminal)

Comment: @ToVine here it is    "Linux sudhirs-desktop 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:41 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux"

Comment: @SudhirK aah, then you're running 32-bit Linux and should take the 32-bit version.  https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/?dv=linux32_deb

Comment: @Toivine, Cody Gray:   I see the point. I think i686 means it is a 32 bit kernel and that must be the issue. Not sure if I can have a 64bit ubuntu on this processor.

Comment: @SudhirK that's correct. You should be able to run 64-bit Ubuntu as well, you can try booting a 64-bit live image